# How to match 2 two multi-dimensional list or array

Tags: python, list, dataframe, multidimensional-array, jupyter-notebook

I am having a bit of trouble finding a code to match 2 two multi-dimensional list or array over 21 rows. For example a1 to find a match in b1 and return the result.

```
a1 = [
    [
        [91,15,25], [4,14,25]
    ],
    [
        [91,115,215], [41,154,148]
    ]
]


b1 = [
    [
        [41,4,14], [3,5,14]
    ],
    [
        [266,41,73], [366,13,91]
    ]
]
```

I have tried to use this code but only works by slicing the index which is time consuming. Is there another option specially with a large list.

```
for l in a1[0]:
    result = []
    for k in b1[0]:
        result.append(list(set(l) & set(k)))
    print(result)

for l in a1[1]:
    result = []
    for k in b1[1]: 
        result.append(list(set(l) & set(k)))
    print(result)
```

If possible I would like my output to be

```
result1 = [[[],[],[4, 14], [14]],
        [[],[91],[41],[]]]
```

then I would like to remove the duplicates.

```
   result2 = [[[4, 14], [14]],
        [[91], [41]]]
```

Comment: Is it intentional that you compare list `a1[0][0]` to `b1[0][0]` and `b1[0][1]` but not `b1[1][0]`or `b1[1][1]`? Also, after removing the empty lists from the result, you loose any implicit knowledge about where the match came from, is that intentional? And, if so, why not combine the lists to `[ [4,14], [9,41] ]`?

Comment: I have a large list this is a small example. Is there a way you can help me

Comment: I'm trying to help, but I asked you for more details. Please answer both my questions to provide those additional details?

Comment: What do you mean by "match" here, exactly?  I don't see any matches in your sample data.

Comment: a1[0][0] to match b1[0][0] and then a1[1][1] to match b1[1][1] and etc. But the problem is it will be time consuming specially if I have a large list. I would like my output to be result1 = [[[],[],[4, 14], [14]],
        [[],[91],[41],[]]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't answer either of my questions, in the comments, so I'm only willing to invest the time to answer half of the question...

Instead of looping, you can use list comprehensions. *(In this case, a comprehension within another comprehension.)*

It does not "remove duplicates".

```
l = \
[
    [
        list(
            set(a_) & set(b_)
        )
        for a_ in a
        for b_ in b
    ]
    for (a, b) in zip(a1, b1)
]

print(l)
```

Demo; https://www.mycompiler.io/new/python?fork=9DHnT2L7mtW

Comment: Works. Appreciate the help.

Comment: What I would do; https://www.mycompiler.io/view/JlNZRWs9I0K

Comment: works but is there a way to get it like this [[[4, 14], [14]],
        [[91], [41]]].  im not trying to remove duplicates the has the same value and another number. hopefully im making sense.

Comment: @Chris `You didn't answer either of my questions, in the comments, so I'm only willing to invest the time to answer half of the question...`

Comment: I thought I did